# Multiple page document upload and display c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I have a functionality where I need to upload a multi-page document. For display purposes, I have to give the user ability to view it page-vise. I have to show no. of pages and then user can navigate back and forth between the pages to view each page.

Any pointers on how this can be accomplished? I am using ASP.Net MVC3 and C# as the language.

Much Thanks!

Comment: What's the format of this document?

Comment: It could be an image, doc, pdf.

Answer (score 0):

If by "multi-page document" you mean like a PDF or word doc, then you'll need to embed a 3rd party viewer in your page and have it display. Generally they have the functionality you've mentioned built-in.

Comment: Are you aware of any tool that can achieve this? Any open source tool?